# What is the difference between .onclick and .addEventListener("click", function())?

Tags: javascript, button, event-listener

New to javascript and I find myself often trying one before realizing the other one is what I need, are they not doing the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are what I found for your questions:
addEventListner:

- Can add multiple events to a particular element.
- Can take a third argument that can control the event propagation.
- Can only be added within  elements or in external JavaScript file.

On the other hand - onclick:

- Can add only a single event to an element, and it is basically a property, so gets overwritten.
- Event propagation cannot be controlled by onclick.
- Can be added as an HTML attribute also.

Also, you can read more about the difference [Here](https://medium.com/@annapeterson89/addeventlistener-vs-onclick-which-one-should-you-draft-into-your-fantasy-football-team-16ea9ae71ee0)